# How do determine at runtime whether an iOS device supports Bluetooth LE

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

What is the correct way to determine whether an iOS device supports Bluetooth LE. Is there a way to query this through CoreBluetooth, or are you required to check iOS versions and hardware ids to figure it out. The latter seems unlikely given Apple's dislike of those approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just setup your `CBCentralManagerDelegate` and wait for the `centralManagerDidUpdateState:` callback. If the state is `CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported`, then the current device does not support ble.

> CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported -> The platform doesn't support the
>   Bluetooth Low Energy Central/Client role.